# How do we generate a cypher query by using Java and APOC for Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, user-defined-functions, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to create my own procedure in Java in order to use it for Neo4j.I wanted to know how we can execute Cypher code in Java ?

I tried to use graphDB.execute() function but it doesn't work.
I just want to execute a basic code in Java by using Neo4j libraries.
Example of a basic code I want to execute:

[EDIT]

```
public class Test
{ 
    @Context public GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    @UserFunction
    public Result test() {

        Result result = graphDb.execute("MATCH (n:Actor)\n" + 
                "RETURN n.name AS name\n" + 
                "UNION ALL MATCH (n:Movie)\n" + 
                "RETURN n.title AS name", new HashMap<String, Object>());


        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `graphDB.execute()` should be a correct approach. You haven't supplied the relevant code, and you haven't described HOW it doesn't work (error messages and such) so we can't help you until you provide that.

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I put my graphDb.execut into a Result so the problem is that I can't return a Result in order to display it on Neo4j. I also edited the post by adding the code.

Comment: I would like to obtain the same output I have on Neo4j but I can't for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display nodes (as in the graphical result view in the browser), then you have to return the nodes themselves (and/or relationships and/or paths), not the properties alone (names and titles). You'll also need this to be a procedure, not a function. Procedures can yield streams of nodes, functions can only return single values.

Change this to a procedure, and change your return type to be something like `Stream<NodeResult>` where NodeResult is a POJO that has a public Node field.

You'll need to change your return accordingly.